# syntax in php for 2d matrix which is exactly like that in C

Tags: php, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array

I want to make a 2d array in php exactly like the ones in C, which can be accessed like mat[i][j]. what would be the syntax?

The following code is what I'm trying to convert from C to PHP:

```
 mat[5][5];
 for(i=0,i<5,i++)
    for (j=0,j<5,j++) {
      mat[i][j]=some value;
    }
```

Comment: Can you at least provide an example or code in C? `$mat[$i][$j] = "value";` ?

Comment: PHP 101: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: @Ofir Baruch Something like this in C mat[5][5];
for(i=0,i<5,i++)
for (j=0,j<5,j++)
{
mat[i][j]=some value;
}

Comment: i need to know how to define such an array in C it use to be simple mat[5][5]; thats all, what is its php counter code?

Comment: You don't need to ;) You can add "cells" ("keys") on-the-fly without being required to define "limits" in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike C, in PHP, you don't need to define the size of the array, you don't even need to tell PHP it's an array. Therefore, the following code will work:

```
for($i=0,$i<5,$i++) {
    for ($j=0,$j<5,$j++) {
      $mat[$i][$j]= "some value";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $matrix = array (
   array(1,2,3),
   array(4,5,6),
   array(7,8,9)
  );
```

Is a 2 d array which makes a 3*3 matrix. `$matrix[1][1]` will return 5

For your question

```
$mat = array();
   for($i=0,$i<5,$i++)
      for ($j=0$,$j<5,$j++) {
         $mat[$i][$j]=some value;
   }
```

Or to fix the array to a certain size

```
$mat = new SplFixedArray(5);
   for($i=0,$i<5,$i++){
      $mat[$i] = new SplFixedArray(5);
      for ($j=0$,$j<5,$j++) {
         $mat[$i][$j]=some value;
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like that :

```
$myArray = [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]];

 for($i=0,$i<count($myArray),$i++) {
  for ($j=0,j<count($myArray[i]),j++) {
     $mat[i][j]=some value;
  }
}
```